# USER defined java class step in pentaho data integration

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, pentaho

- Hi,

  I am using the below code in USER DEFINED JAVA CLASS:

  ```
   //STEP 1. Import required packages import java.sql.*;  
  import  org.pentaho.di.core.database.*;
    public class JDBCExample  {    
  // JDBC driver name and database URL      
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
        static final String DB_URL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:1111/mysql";

   //  Database credentials    
         static final String USER = "USER"; 
         static final String PASS = "PASS";
       public static void main(String[] args) {    
       Connection conn = null;    
       Statement stmt = null;    try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


   //STEP 3: Open a connection
   System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
   System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

   //STEP 4: Execute a query
   System.out.println("Creating statement...");
   stmt = conn.createStatement();

   String sql = "select id,sorname,src_databasetype,src_databasename from table";
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
   //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
   while(rs.next()){
      //Retrieve by column name
      int id  = rs.getInt("id");
      String sorname = rs.getString("sorname");
      String src_databasetype = rs.getString("src_databasetype");
      String src_databasename = rs.getString("src_databasename");

      //Display values
      System.out.print("ID: " + id);
      System.out.print(", sorname: " + sorname);
      System.out.print(", src_databasetype: " + src_databasetype);
      System.out.println(", src_databasename: " + src_databasename);
   }
   rs.close();    }catch(SQLException se){
   //Handle errors for JDBC
   se.printStackTrace();    }catch(Exception e){
   //Handle errors for Class.forName
   e.printStackTrace();    }finally{
   //finally block used to close resources
   try{
      if(stmt!=null)
         conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
   }// do nothing
   try{
      if(conn!=null)
         conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      se.printStackTrace();
   }//end finally try    }//end try    System.out.println("Goodbye!"); }//end main }//end JDBCExample
  ```

  Running the code through command prompt its working fine

  BUT on running the step(In PDI) alone I am getting error: 
  **Non-abstract class "Processor" must implement method "boolean org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.TransformClassBase.processRow(org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepMetaInterface,
  org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepDataInterface) throws
  org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException"**

Comment: Error was not from your code snippet shown in the Posting. But in a class called `Processor`, which I believe from the same package `org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass`. It did not implement the abstract method `processRow`, inherited from the parent.

Comment: what should I do...I am not using processRow

Comment: But, when you are extending the parent `Processor` abstract class, you ***MUST** implement all abstract methods* from the parent, with at least default functionality.

Comment: I am new to java...please tell me what exactly I am supposed to do....or if u can modify the above code and send it to me.

Comment: Read [*Java- How to use Abstract class*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669638/java-how-to-use-abstract-class)

Answer (score 3):

For UDJC, I think instead of putting code in the main method, you need to put it in processRow().

Instead of using - 
public static void main(String[] args)
use -
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException

I am still skeptical if its still going to work as I don't understand what you're trying to do with that code.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing your code in processRow method as follows:

```
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException{


    Object[] r = getRow();

    if (r == null) {
      setOutputDone();
      return false;
    }
    Object[] outputRow = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());

    //String row = getString(r)+",";
    //setValue(outputRow, row)
    putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRow);

    return true;

}
```